# Select minimum value from column A where column B is not in an array

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, odbc

I'm trying to select accesses for patients where `d11.xblood` is a minimum value grouped by `d11.xpid` - and where  `d11.xcaccess_type` is not 288, 289, or 292. (`d11.xblood` is a chronological index of accesses.)

- `d11.xpid`: Patient ID (int)
- `d11.xblood`: Unique chronological index of patients' accesses (int)
- `d11.xcaccess_type`: Unique identifier for accesses (int)

I want to report one row for each `d11.xpid` where `d11.xblood` is the minimum (initial access) for its respective `d11.xpid` . Moreover, I want to exclude the row if the initial access for a `d11.xpid` has a `d11.xcaccess_type` value of 288, 289 or 292.

I have tried several variations of this in the Select Expert:

```
{d11.xblood} = Minimum({d11.xblood},{d11.xpid}) and
not ({d11.xcaccess_type} in [288, 289, 292])
```

This correctly selects rows with the initial access but eliminates rows where the *current* access is not in the array. I only want to eliminate rows where the *initial* access is not in the array. How can I accomplish this?

Sample table:

```
xpid   xblood   xcaccess_type
----   ------   -------------
1       98       400
1       49       300
1       152      288
2       33       288
2       155      300
2       70       400
3       40       300
3       45       400
```

Sample desired output:

```
xpid   xblood   xcaccess_type
----   ------   -------------
1       49       300
3       40       300
```

See that `xpid = 2` is not in the output because its minimum value of `xblood` had an `xcaccess_type = 288` which is excluded. Also see that even though `xpid = 1` has an `xcaccess_type = 288`, because there is a lower value of `xblood` for `xpid = 1` where `xcaccess_type not in (288,289,292)` it is still included.

Comment: Can you explain better please ?  initial/current  access ? What does that mean and what is this ? This code seems good for what you want to achieve in my opinion

Comment: You should include a sample table along with what you want for sample output.  This gives us better context.

Comment: Added a little more info. Let me know if I can clear anything else up.

Comment: Sample table/output added as well.

Comment: Every crystal report concern please clarify expound specifically what result you need, what process,what do you want to do in crystal report itself(formula,parameter etc.). Include your needs clearly.

Comment: @reds Let me know if there is any additional info that would help solve this, seems pretty clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write a stored procedure or custom SQL to handle this, you could add another Group. Assuming your deepest group (the one closest to the Details section) is sorting based on `xpid`, you could add a group inside that one which sorts the `xcaccess_type` from lowest to highest.

Suppress the header and footer for the new group then add this clause to the details section:

```
({d11.xpid} = PREVIOUS({d11.xpid})
OR
({d11.xcaccess_type} in [288, 289, 292])
```

This should modify your report to only ever display the records with the *lowest* access value per person. And if the lowest access value is one of the three forbidden values, no records will show for that `xpid`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, adding the `xcaccess_type` grouping inside the `xpid` grouping was the missing piece!